# Angularjs directive element.on('change') not firing

Tags: angularjs

I'm using this directive for uploading files. The file has a label that comes a long with it. I have a function I call before I try to upload and if that function returns false then I don't want to do the upload because they user didn't give a label value.

The issue seems to be when I just return from the element.on('change') callback it never gets called again. When I return $.ajax() when everything works the element.on('change') gets triggered as many times as I want. So I'm not sure why just calling return stops element.on('change') from triggering in future upload tries.

```
angular.module('ngSimpleUpload', [])
    .directive('ngSimpleUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
        return {
            scope: {
                webApiUrl: '@',
                callbackFn: '=',
                errorFn: '=',
                preFn: '=',
                selectedFileFn: '=',
                additionalData: '=',
                buttonId: '@'
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                // original code, trigger upload on change
                element.on('change', function (evt) {
                    var files = evt.__files_ || (evt.target && evt.target.files);
                    Upload(files);
                });

                function Upload(files) {
                    // can bail out of the entire call if preupload returns false
                    if (scope.preFn(scope.additionalData) == false) {
                        return;
                    }

                    var fd = new FormData();

                    angular.forEach(files, function (v, k) {
                        fd.append('file', files[k]);
                        scope.selectedFileFn(files[k].name);
                    });

                    return $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: scope.$eval(scope.webApiUrl),
                        data: fd,
                        async: true,
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false
                    }).done(function (d) {
                        // callback function in the controller
                        scope.callbackFn(d, scope.additionalData);
                    }).fail(function (x) {
                        // callback function in the controller
                        scope.errorFn(x);
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, it turns out the issue is the element value wasn't getting cleared out so the change wouldn't fire. I added element.val(null) when the pre failed and that worked.